# Как в VS 2015 в консольное приложения подключить в referances библиотеки? C++

Tags: c++, windows, winforms, консоль

Всем привет, у меня есть консольное приложение, хочу добавить к нему Windows Form, для этого нужно добавить библиотеки.С помощью окна Add references не получается по скольку там нет кнопок add, Browsr или COM. Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить в консольное приложение referances или как добавить в консоль Windows Form?

Заранее спаибо!!

Comment: Скорее всего Ваше консольное приложение написано на нормальном с++. А Вы пытаетесь подключить к нему Windows Form (а это .NET). Что делать? Либо переписать под .net Ваше консольное приложение, либо использовать WinAPI для построения интерфейса.

Comment: Переписать не вариант, как использовать WinAPI?

Comment: тут ещё не факт, что Вам будет проще. Гугл и вперед. Хотя я бы посмотрел на Qt или что то подобное. Там gui будет проще сделать.

Все зависит от того, что именно Вам нужно в GUI.

Comment: ок,Спасибо! Попробую

Answer (score 0):

1. Открыть референсы
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Отметить требуемые библиотеки галочкой (используйте поиск)
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Сохранить кликнув "Ок"

Comment: Вы по-моему путаете c# и c++

Comment: Спасибо, исправил

Comment: как  KoVadim написал выше и я писал о том, что там нету Browse, COM и т.п., у меня кажется баз .Net написано

Comment: А вы как создавали проект? Вам нужно это http://i.imgur.com/gy0lUnq.png

Comment: Человеку не нужен недо с++, который из дотнета.  Пора уже вводить метку "это чистый с++, без дотнета":)

Comment: В данном случае метка будет называться "это чистый с++, без дотнета, но с дотнетовскими формами" :D